# Talking to a motor driver through a CAN-BUS

Tags: windows, hardware, usb, can-bus, motordriver

I have a motor, connected to a motor
    driver, connected a windows XP
    computer by a CAN-BUS (through USB I believe).
    I want to "talk" to the motor driver
    and have some questions:

- Does the USB appear as a COM port?
- What protocol do I
  use or how do I find out what
  protocol to use? Or how do I talk to it?
- Does anyone
  have or know of any public
  implementations of a similar
  thing that I can look at?
- Are there any other hints you want to share?

  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, the USB device will probably appear as a COM port. Just open the hardware manager window in Windows, plug in your USB device and see if it creates a new COM port.
2. The CAN protocol of course! You have to order it from CAN-CIA but I believe it's free: http://www.can-cia.org/index.php (click on the download section)
3. Not that I know of.
4. I'd suggest downloading the relevant specs and start reading. It looks like there's lots of reading to be done.